# timestamp of time(0) at multiple places in a C++ program

Tags: c++, time, timestamp

Why is the timestamp of time(0) at multiple places in a C++ program the same value?

Ex:

```
int main(){
     cout << time(0) << endl;
     cout << time(0) << endl;
     cout << time(0) << endl;
     cout << time(0) << endl; 
   }
```

All of the values above are the same. Is this because the program is executed at such a fast speed that the time values in the above example are all the same?

Could someone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The resolution of the [`time()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time) function isn't fine grained enough to result in different values to make a different result for each call you make, i.e. the CPU is faster.

You might try to insert [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) calls to check what timing resolution fits for your needs with the hardware and OS you have at hand.

Answer (score 0):

The `time(0)` function returns the current time in seconds.

The code that you upload will run all the code in one second.
Therefore, even if the time is output, all the same time is output.

The following code is to output the current time continuously for 3 seconds.
If you run it, you will see a lot of numbers, but if you look closely you can see that the number changes three times.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    time_t s = std::time(0); // time_t is int64 in windows 10 64bit.
    time_t n;

    do {
        n = std::time(0);
        std::cout << n << " ";
    } while ((s + 3) > n); // repeat until 3 sec passed.

    return 0;
}
```